# Add not Concatenate Objects in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I am trying to GET total order prices (in USD) in an object array and sum the total. Instead of summing the array, the order totals are concatenated. How do I force addition instead of concatenation?

```
<body>
<p id=sales></p>
<script>
var sales, i, x = "";

sales = {"orders": [{"total_price_usd": "92.05"}, {"total_price_usd": "14.90"}, {"total_price_usd": "17.90"}, {"total_price_usd": "14.90"}]}

for (i in sales.orders) {
    x += sales.orders[i].total_price_usd + ', ';
}
var numbers = [x];
function getSum(total, num) {
    return parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(num);
}
document.getElementById('sales').innerHTML = '$' + numbers.reduce(getSum);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: That's not [JSON](https://json.org). _"JSON is a textual, language-indepedent data-exchange format, much like XML, CSV or YAML."_ - [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: `numbers` just contains a long, comma-separated string, how do you expect to be able to parse it as a number?

Comment: 1. The value of `total_price_usd` is a string. 2. If you want to sum numbers why do you then add `', '`?

Comment: The server returns the total prices as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `parseFloat()` on the variables and initialising x to 0 should help

```js
var sales, i, x = 0;

sales = {"orders": [{"total_price_usd": "92.05"}, {"total_price_usd": "14.90"}, {"total_price_usd": "17.90"}, {"total_price_usd": "14.90"}]}

for (i in sales.orders) {
    x += parseFloat(sales.orders[i].total_price_usd);
}
var numbers = [x];
function getSum(total, num) {
    return parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(num);
}
document.getElementById('sales').innerHTML = '$' + numbers.reduce(getSum);
```

```html
<div id="sales"></div>
```

Do note that adding floating point numbers in Javascript can lead to some pretty common discrepancies. 
[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: The `numbers` array is completely pointless, as is the call to `.reduce()`

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't create an array of numbers:

```
var numbers = [x];
```

It's just creating an array with one element, a string, as if you'd written:

```
var numbers = ["92.05, 14.90, 17.90, 14.90"]
```

Then when you call `numbers.reduce()`, it just processes the first number in the string, it doesn't loop over them. Using a variable that contains a string doesn't cause it to parsed as if it were Javascript source.

You should do:

```
var numbers = []
for (var i = 0; i < sales.order.length; i++) {
    numbers.push(parseFloat(sales.order[i].total_price_usd));
}
```

Or you can just do the addition in this loop, instead of using `reduce()` later:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < sales.order.length; i++) {
    total += parseFloat(sales.order[i].total_price_usd);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a micro-optimization that's unlikely to be significant in most programs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `reduce` and the `Number` constructor:

```js
sales = {"orders": [{"total_price_usd": "92.05"}, {"total_price_usd": "14.90"}, {"total_price_usd": "17.90"}, {"total_price_usd": "14.90"}]}

const total = sales.orders.reduce(
  (total, order) => total + Number(order.total_price_usd), 
  0
)

console.log(total)
```

`parseFloat` and the unary `+` will also work, as others point out.  I think Number is the most readable, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: How does this solve the real problem? It just seems like a style change, but the bug still exists.

Comment: What real problem do you see?  I start with the initial data and return the expected total.  I suppose I don't explain what's wrong with the original, but it seemed like the question was about getting addition instead of concatenation.  I'll add a snippet.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that you changed the variable you're looping over, I thought you just changed `parseFloat` to `Number`.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  Yes, that wouldn't do much.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- You can access directly to array `sales.orders`
- Within function `getSum` get the price in USD `num.total_price_usd`

```js
var sales = {"orders": [{"total_price_usd": "92.05"}, {"total_price_usd": "14.90"}, {"total_price_usd": "17.90"}, {"total_price_usd": "14.90"}]};


//------------- You need to verify this logic
var i, x = ""

// You're creating an array as follow: ["1, 2, 4, 5"].
for (i in sales.orders) {
    x += sales.orders[i].total_price_usd + ', ';
}
var numbers = [x];
//-------------------------------------------

function getSum(total, num) {
    return parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(num.total_price_usd);
}

document.getElementById('sales').innerHTML = '$' + sales.orders.reduce(getSum, 0);
```

```html
<p id=sales></p>
```

Comment: Why did you keep the first loop with `x` and the `numbers` variable that you're not using any more?

Comment: @Barmar to illustrate the problem that OP is facing.